# How to check global events inside an infinite loop within a class?

Tags: architecture, d

I'm writing a little program to perform some database operations and have a small question about design.

Part of my program watches a log file for changes and this involves code which is wrapped up in a class. So the usage is something like this:

```
auto fileWatcher = new FileWatcher(fileName);
fileWatcher.onChange(delegate);
fileWatcher.start();
```

Once the start method is called a loop is entered within the class and the file is watched. Changes are handle through calling the registered delegate. The loop uses different watch methods for different platforms.

What i need to be able to do is to stop the current watch and change the watched file.

Because this is in an infinite loop, i can't check externally i.e. outside of the class, if i need to break from the loop simply because control never returns to the caller of the `start()` method.

Am i missing something simple here? Any advice is welcome. I thought about threading and message passing but that's maybe overkill for something as simple as this?

Answer (score 1):

spawn another thread to do the checking

you can do a `while(!atomicLoad(stop)){` in the loop and call a `stop()` method that sets the member field `stop` to `true` with a a `atomicStore(stop,true)` both from `core.atomic`

Comment: `spawn(&(cast(shared)this).run);`

Comment: Does `run` have to be static? because i'm getting an error using that code. i.e. it doesn't match any function template declaration. Have you got a larger example please?